# Не могу сохранить изменения в файле. Работаю в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Поставил LAMP. Потом стала задача

> Свои настройки следует писать в /etc/apache2/conf.d, т.е. создать там
> файл, например, myconf.conf и определить в нём свои настройки.

Вот это не удается сделать так как не могу сохранить изменения в файле. Причина наверное - недостаточно прав.
Так же самое не могу менять все нужные мне файлы в папке /etc.
Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос банален до невозможности. Посмотрите права на файлы и директории. Они будут root:root в /etc. Редактируйте с правами root - в вашем случае, через sudo.